# angularjs not loading partials

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm trying to put together a basic angularjs web page through django (but not really using django for this example). I tried to copy an example exactly, but it's not working. The partial and the controller are not loading. The url is updated, so I know the app is loading. But I don't see it hitting my web server at all for the partial or the data. Help would be appreciated.

Here is the simplest code I could put together.

test.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ciqApp">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        TEST
        <div ng-view>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

js/app.js

```
var ciqApp = angular.module('ciqApp', [
        'ngRoute',
        'ciqControllers'
        ]);

ciqApp.config(['$routeProvider',
        function($routeProvider){
            $routeProvider.
                when('/questions', {
                    templateURL: '/static/partials/question-list.html',
                    controller: 'QuestionListCtrl'
                }).
                otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/questions'
                });
        }]);
```

js/controllers.js

```
var ciqControllers = angular.module('ciqControllers', []);

ciqControllers.controller('QuestionListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
        function ($scope, $http) {
            $http.get('/get_questions').success(function(data) {
                $scope.questions = data;
            });
        }]);
```

Comment: Any error output from the js console?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TemplateURL should be TemplateUrl. Also, you can try to remove the first slash from your templateUrl path and see if that makes a difference:  So:

```
templateURL: '/static/partials/question-list.html',
```

becomes:

```
templateUrl: 'static/partials/question-list.html',
```

Comment: Yup. Url, not URL. I knew it had to be something simple. So close!!